# How to create two table with same struct

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using gorm to create two sqlite table of same struct, in order to have different table name, I have following:

```
type Reservation struct {
   ID string
    ...
    ...
}
func (Reservation) TableName() string {
    return "reservations"
}

type Record struct {
    Reservation
}

func (Record) TableName() string {
    return "records"
}
```

and two tables are created using gorm AutoMigrate.

```
legDb, err := legacyGorm.Open(r.driver, r.filePath)
legDb.AutoMigrate(i...)
```

They do have different name, and in sqlite they look same.

But when I try to query the "records" table using Reservation struct, it can't return any result. It works if I query with Record struct

```
var res Reservation
db.Order("last_activity_at DESC").First(&res, "id = ?", identity)
```

How can I use same struct (Reservation) to create two table (different table name) with same schema? For my code above, it does looks like same schema, but query using Reservation won't give me result in "records" table.

Comment: Why do you want to create two tables with different names but the same schema?

Comment: @NG235 I have use case to sync another table of different schema into first one, and they have conflict and different cases that I will use query to compare & filter.

Comment: Could you just create two identical structs?

Comment: Additionally, is there rows in both tables to query?